# How to easily Bind any database VIEWS to a jtable with netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, view, jtable, bind

Netbeans can easily bind jtable with relational database tables(mysql,deby,etc)..
How can i easily bind "Views" table to a jtable...
If that is not possible, is there any easy way to join tables and display the result in JTable... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy to display an arbitrary ResultSet in a JTable. You first need to work out what columns there are by using the metadata within the ResultSet and then add rows by looping over the ResultSet.
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2010/02/display-any-resultset-in-jtable.html